# How to efficiently process and filter large CSV files in Python?

Tags: python

I am working with large CSV files (several gigabytes in size) and need to process and filter the data efficiently using Python. The goal is to extract specific rows based on certain conditions and perform calculations on the selected data.

Here's the problem I am facing:

Reading the entire CSV file into memory using pandas or csv module results in high memory usage and slow processing due to the file size.
Iterating through the CSV file line by line is time-consuming, especially when applying complex filtering conditions.
The traditional approach of loading the entire file and then filtering using pandas' DataFrame operations is not feasible due to memory constraints.

I attempted to use pandas' chunksize parameter to read the CSV file in smaller chunks, but it still consumes a significant amount of memory and doesn't provide the desired performance improvement.
I explored using Dask to parallelize the processing of large CSV files, but I'm uncertain about the optimal approach and how to efficiently implement filtering operations.
I considered using a database management system like SQLite, but I'm unsure if it would be a suitable solution for this particular task.
I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches on how to handle and efficiently process large CSV files in Python, specifically focusing on memory-efficient methods for filtering and extracting relevant data.

Thank you for your help and expertise!

Comment: There's always a trade-off between memory use and performance.  The best memory profile is by making a traditional Unix filter -- a simple read / process / write loop, especially if you don't need any interactions between the rows.  SQLite is clearly the wrong answer if performance is an issue, but perhaps a real client/server product like MySQL or Postgres could give you what you need.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the filtering you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

[Polars](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/) is a Pandas alternative that comes with its own, much faster, CSV parser. Because Polars internally uses Arrow, you might see a reduction in memory usage too.

If a one-off conversion to another format is acceptable, try converting the CSV to Parquet. Both Pandas and Polars can read this out of the box, and it's one to two orders of magnitude faster than CSV.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions that comes to my mind right now:

1. Use `chunksize` with Pandas

`pd.read_csv(data, chunksize=1000)`

2. Use Dask with Pandas

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
start = time.time()
dask_df = dd.read_csv('huge_data.csv')
end = time.time()
print("Read csv with dask: ",(end-start),"sec")
Read csv with dask:  0.07900428771972656 sec
```